# Multiple actions in one cronjob

Tags: shell, cron

I have this crontab :

```
0 05 * * * /usr/src/app/infrastructure/my_script.sh something_from_my_script >> /var/log/logger.log 2>&1
50 05 * * * /usr/src/app/infrastructure/my_script.sh something_from_my_script >> /var/log/logger.log 2>&1
0 05 * * * /usr/src/app/infrastructure/my_script.sh something_from_my_script >> /var/log/logger.log 2>&1
50 05 * * * /usr/src/app/infrastructure/my_script.sh something_from_my_script >> /var/log/logger.log 2>&1
```

How can I concatenate the crons that are starting at the same time in one line ?
This is just a sample from the crontab that I have there times when I have 10-15 actions and I need to concatenate them in one line.

Any ideas ?

Comment: naive way could be just run it through `crontab -l | sort | uniq`, but this can mess up things like comments

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
 0 05 * * * /usr/src/app/infrastructure/my_script.sh something_from_my_script >> /var/log/logger.log 2>&1 || /usr/src/app/infrastructure/my_script.sh something_from_my_script >> /var/log/logger.log 2>&1
50 05 * * * /usr/src/app/infrastructure/my_script.sh something_from_my_script >> /var/log/logger.log 2>&1 || /usr/src/app/infrastructure/my_script.sh something_from_my_script >> /var/log/logger.log 2>&1
```